# get updated row in one to many mapping using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I have two entities Issue and `Issue_Tracker`. I have joined both table in an one to many mapping. In `Issue_Tracker` , We can have multiple entries like

```java
  issue_id  tracker_status      tracked_time
    123     Assigned           1/8/2013 11:44
    123     Assigned           1/8/2013 11:45
    123     Completed          1/8/2013 11:52
    32      Assigned           1/9/2013 16:46
    33      Assigned           1/9/2013 16:47
    33      Cancel             1/9/2013 16:49
```

I want to Order the Issue_tracker entity by tracked_time so I can get only last update `tracker_status`.I am using criteria to get data,However I am getting first entry for example : for issue_id 123, I get tracker_status as Assigned , But I want to fetch `tracker_status : Completed` for id 123. How to achieve this. My DAO is as follows

```java
     Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Issue.class);
     criteria.setFirstResult(from);
     criteria.setMaxResults(size);
     criteria.setFetchMode("Issue.issueTracker",FetchMode.JOIN);
     criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", "Escalate To"));
      return criteria.list();
```

**Issue.java**

```java
public class Issue implements Serializable
        {
        private Integer issue_id;
        private String  issue_description;
        private Date issue_raised_date;
        private Set<Issue_Tracker> issueTracker = new HashSet<Issue_Tracker>(0);



        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="issue_id")
        public Set<Issue_Tracker> getIssueTracker() {
        return issueTracker;
    }

        public void setIssueTracker(Set<Issue_Tracker> issueTracker) {
        this.issueTracker = issueTracker;
```

**Issue_Tracker.java**

```java
public class Issue_Tracker implements Serializable
{  
     private Integer   issue_id;
     private String    tracker_status;
     private Timestamp tracked_time;
```

I hope you guys can get what i am trying to ask, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an @OrderBy annotation to the mapped collection.  This should return the entities in the set ordered by the tracked time.  The first entity in the set should be the latest.

```
//Issue.java
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="issue_id")
    @OrderBy("tracked_time DESC")
    public Set<Issue_Tracker> getIssueTracker() {
    return issueTracker;
```

You may also want to try:

```
 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Issue.class);
 criteria.setFirstResult(from);
 criteria.setMaxResults(size);
 criteria.setFetchMode("Issue.issueTracker",FetchMode.JOIN);
 criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", "Escalate To"));
 Criteria subCriteria = criteria.createCriteria("issueTracker");
 subCriteria.addOrder(Order.desc("tracked_time"));
 return criteria.list();
```

Comment: thanks but not working getting this error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: antlr.TokenStream

Comment: A jar file in missing from the application's libraries: http://www.findjar.com/class/antlr/TokenStream.html

Comment: Ok, Executed but no really changes ,I am getting the same result, Still fetching the first row ,not last one

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk I may have missed the point of what you wanted to accomplish.  My first solution would result in the call to getIssueTracker returning an ordered set.  I think your attempting to order the parents, check out the other solution.  Warning it is untested