# Hibernate one-to-many mapping - to fetch only one mapped record based on a criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, one-to-many

Problem : There is a transaction table and status table with one-to-many mapping. One transaction can have multiple statuses like failed, partially paid and success. How to fetch the latest status of a transaction.

i.e, If I have a transaction with multiple statuses like failed and success of which success is the latest one. Is there any way to configure the same in hibernate to fetch one record from status table based on date field or any other field?

I have been searching for best way for my problem, though I have some ways to do the same using comparable and compare to in java, I am still wondering if there is any solution that hibernate provides where we can simply configure it in hbm files and get the output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Filters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch19.html) in hibernate by which you can filter out the data in `OneToMany` Collection. Also take a look [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-data-filter-example-xml-and-annotation/) as an example.

Comment: I went through these filters, this is much like comparison of collection with external parameters, can I use these filters to compare the collection or sort the same?

Comment: I found the solution here "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255493/get-updated-row-in-one-to-many-mapping-using-hibernate", thank you Shailendra for your response.